# Using ArcPy SeachCursor in Point SHP to define new variable made of point coordinates?

Tags: arcpy, coordinates, cursor

I have a polyline, and I am trying to extract the endpoint x,y coordinates to define them as variables.

For example, if I want to define as `PtA = 551799.478099, 3762853.77587`; and `PtB =561687.918363, 3764343.32249` (of course these change as I loop over multiple lines.I'm having trouble understanding/utilizing the SearchCursor concept.

I was trying to dump "PtA" and "PtB" into "testAB"

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

centerLine = r'C:\Users\X\Documents\_temp working\center_line.shp'
outpath = r'C:\Users\X\Documents\_temp working'

# Set local variables
inFeatures = centerLine
outFeatureClass = outpath + '\\' + 'centerLine_vertices.shp'
pointLocation = "BOTH_ENDS"

# Execute FeatureVerticesToPoints
arcpy.FeatureVerticesToPoints_management(inFeatures, outFeatureClass, pointLocation)


# this prints the xy coords, but how to save as variable?
for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(outFeatureClass, ["SHAPE@XY"]):
        # Print x,y coordinates of each point feature
        x, y = row[0]
        print("{}, {}".format(x, y))


# this doesn't work, something wrong with how I have set up "test"?
testAB = []
counter = 0
for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(outFeatureClass, ["SHAPE@XY"]):
    testAB[counter] = row[0]
    counter += 1

print test
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like what you're trying to do is to create a [Python dictionary](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp) so that you can access the coordinates later.

To achieve this you could do something like this:

```
testAB = {} # curly braces denote a dict() type
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(outFeatureClass, ['SHAPE@XY']) as rows:
    for index, row in enumerate(rows):
        testAB[index] = row[0]

# now you can access the first like:
print testAB[0]
```

However, I think it would be more useful to use the OID as the key:

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(outFeatureClass, ['OID@', 'SHAPE@XY']) as rows:
    testAB = dict(r for r in rows)

# print coordinates for OBJECTID # 128
print testAB[128]
```

Alternatively, if you just need to temporarily access the coordinates within the loop and do something with them, you can just do that in the loop itself.

On an unrelated note, `test` was not defined in your code so that would have thrown an error.

Comment: Many thanks @crmackey! I went with the second option as suggested, and worked like a (py)charm